# How to find number in list which has the biggest number of prime factors?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to write a program that receives 10 entries and at the end it should print the number that has the greatest number of prime factors along with the number of its prime factors in the output. And, if some of the inputs have the same condition, the program will print the biggest one.

The code that I wrote executed all conditions except the final condition.
How should I write a code for a case where two numbers have the same numbers of prime factors (when I want the bigger number to be my output)?
For example both 678 and 84 have 3 prime factors . The output of my code is 84, while I want the output to be 678 (the bigger number)

Comment: Provide your code and also add expected inputs and outputs for better understanging.

Comment: put your code in your question

Comment: Welcome to SO, please edit your question and put your codes in the question. also take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 2):

You want to find **number in list which has the biggest number of prime factors**.

You can try the following code. :)

This code finds the numbers in a given list ( say `lst`) which have the largest numbers of prime factors. It compares the said numbers and outputs the biggest number (from among numbers which have the largest number of prime factors).

```
import numpy as np

''' lst: list data type. (Some sample list with 10 numbers.) '''
lst = [123,43,54,12,76,84,98,678,543,231]

''' Function which returns numbers of prime factors. '''
def prime_factors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = []
    while i * i <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            factors.append(i)
    if n > 1:
        factors.append(n)
    return np.unique(factors)


''' 
num_prime_factors : list data type. (stores numbers of unique prime factors of each element in lst.)
maxx : int data type (max value of num_prime_factors.)
max_indices : list data type (indices of elements of list which have maximum numbers of prime factors.)
values : (largest number in lst which has maximum number of prime factors.)
'''
num_prime_factors = [ len( prime_factors(lst[i]) ) for i in range(len(lst)) ]
maxx = max(num_prime_factors)
max_indices = [i for i, j in enumerate(num_prime_factors) if j == maxx]
values = sorted( [ lst[max_indices[i]] for i in range(len(max_indices)) ] )[-1]

print('Number with greatest number of prime factors: ', values)
print('Largest number of prime factors: ', maxx)

>> ('Number with greatest number of prime factors: ', 678)
>> ('Largest number of prime factors: ', 3)
```